# Tabla de multiplicar del 1 al 10 Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el cual por pantalla me tienen que salir las diez tablas de multiplicar, de esta manera.

He conseguido hacerlo pero no consigo que los títulos de las tablas ("Tabla del 1, tabla del 2...) me salgan bien. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

En el ejercicio solo se puede utilizar while y if/else. Nada de for ni de otras cosas distintas.

El código que tengo escrito yo es el siguiente:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        int tabla = 1;
        int multiplicador = 1;
        int resultado = 0;

        while (tabla <= 10) {
            resultado = tabla * multiplicador;
            System.out.println(+tabla + "*" + multiplicador + "=" + +resultado);
            multiplicador = multiplicador + 1;

            if (multiplicador == 11) {
                System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + tabla);
                multiplicador = 1;
                tabla = tabla + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien la respuesta anterior es correcta considero, podemos perfeccionarla para lograr el resultado de salida exacto que se propone:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int tabla = 1;
     int multiplicador = 1;
     int resultado = 0;

     while (tabla < 11) {
        if (multiplicador==1)
            System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + tabla);
            
        resultado = tabla * multiplicador;
        System.out.println(tabla + "*" + multiplicador + "=" + resultado);
        multiplicador = multiplicador + 1;

        if (multiplicador > 10) {
            multiplicador = 1;
            tabla = tabla + 1;
            System.out.println("---------");
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Observa que uso la variable multiplicador para saber cuando he de mostrar el título da la tabla. Cuando multiplicador es 1 es cuando se va a iniciar a escribir la tabla y por eso aprovechamos para  mostrar primero el título.
Y cuando el multiplicador supera 10 es otra tabla e imprimimos unos guiones de separación.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que tampoco te falta mucho para tener lo que necesitas, para empezar deberías mostrar el título para la tabla del 1 antes de entrar en el bucle `while` y añadiendo la condición de que el título de la siguiente tabla se muestre sólo hasta la del 10:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int tabla = 1;
        int multiplicador = 1;
        int resultado = 0;

        System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + tabla);

        while (tabla <= 10) {
            resultado = tabla * multiplicador;
            System.out.println(tabla + "*" + multiplicador + "=" + resultado);
            multiplicador = multiplicador + 1;

            if (multiplicador == 11 && tabla < 11) {
                System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + tabla);
                multiplicador = 1;
                tabla = tabla + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```